# Haskell: Trouble updating/detecting cabal

Tags: haskell, ghc, ubuntu-16.04, cabal

I have both ghci versions 7.10 and 8 installed on my Ubuntu 16.04. I want to install something based on cabal. I already have cabal installed as the command

```
cabal --version
```

yields

```
cabal-install version 1.22.6.0
using version 1.22.5.0 of the Cabal library
```

But when I go to update with

```
cabal update
```

I get

```
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
cabal: does not exist
```

So I am not sure what is going on or how to resolve this. I hope to afterwards install `gloss` which is based on cabal. But

```
cabal install gloss-examples
```

yields

```
Resolving dependencies...
Downloading bindings-DSL-1.0.23...
Downloading bmp-1.2.6.3...
Failed to install bmp-1.2.6.3
Downloading vector-0.10.12.3...
Build log ( /home/username/.cabal/logs/bmp-1.2.6.3.log ):
cabal: /home/username/.cabal/logs/bmp-1.2.6.3.log: does not exist
```

EDIT: I originally installed ghci 7.10. Then later installed ghci 8. Could this have any effect?

EDIT2: After installing

```
cabal install Cabal cabal-install
```

I still get the same error with

```
cabal update
```

Also I still cannot

```
cabal install gloss-examples
```

But I get a different error this time

```
Resolving dependencies...
Downloading bindings-DSL-1.0.23...
Downloading bmp-1.2.6.3...
Failed to install bindings-DSL-1.0.23
Downloading vector-0.10.12.3...
Build log ( /home/aa/.cabal/logs/bindings-DSL-1.0.23.log ):
cabal: /home/aa/.cabal/logs/bindings-DSL-1.0.23.log: does not exist
```

EDIT3: When I installed Cabal, it says that I installed

```
Installed cabal-install-1.24.0.2
```

But when I check with 
    cabal --version

I am still stuck at

```
cabal-install version 1.22.6.0
```

which tells me somehow they are not linked.

Comment: `youProbablyWantCapitalCabal` is maybe a hint...

Comment: Thanks. But it still doesn't solve everything.

Comment: Aside from using cabal in your global userspace being a bad idea(see haskellstack.org) i guess .cabal/bin is not in your path

Comment: @ epsilonhalbe . It is in my path.

Comment: Could you give us the output of: ls .cabal/bin, ./.cabal/bin/cabal -- version, ghc-pkg list, echo $PATH,  where cabal ?

Comment: Also editing out old error messages someone referred to is confusing

Comment: @epsilonhalbe I only have a file called "cabal" inside .cabal/bin and nothing else. I don't understand the rest of what you said.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136737/discussion-between-epsilonhalbe-and-domoremath).